# Is a self join the correct association to use for a pokemon and its evolutions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to work on the correct association between a pokemon and its evolutions. I think I am close to the right answer but I'm having problems trying to model this to completion. This is the goal I a trying to accomplish.

```
bulbasaur = Pokemon.find(1)
bulbasaur.evolved_forms ---> [ivysaur, venasaur]

ivysaur = Pokemon.find(2)
ivysaur.evolved_forms ----> [venusaur]
ivysaur.pre-evolved_forms ---> [bulbasaur]

venusaur = Pokemon.find(3)
venusaur.evolved_forms ----> []
venusaur.pre-evolved_forms ---> [ivysaur, bulbasaur]
```

I have the following model.

```
class Pokemon < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :evolved_forms, class_name: "Pokemon", foreign_key: "pre-evolved_form_id"
   belongs_to :pre-evolved_form, class_name: "Pokemon", optional: true

   has_many :pre-evolved_forms, class_name: "Pokemon", foreign_key: "evolved_form_id"
   belongs_to :evolved_form, class_name: "Pokemon", optional: true
end
```

This seems doable but I feel as if there is something missing like there should be some kind of has many through association. If anyone has a better modeling I would appreciate the feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, there's something better, but I'll do it (nestedly) like below. It also works with Eevie and other pokemons that can have multiple evolution lines.

```rb
class Pokemon < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :previous_evolved_form, class_name: 'Pokemon', optional: true
  has_many :next_evolved_forms, class_name: 'Pokeomn', foreign_key: :previous_evolved_form_id

  def ancestor_evolved_forms
    forms = {}
    
    if previous_evolved_form.present?
      forms[previous_evolved_form] = previous_evolved_form.ancestor_evolved_forms
    end
  end

  def descendant_evolved_forms
    forms = {}
    
    next_evolved_forms.each do |next_evolved_form|
      forms[next_evolved_form] = next_evolved_form.descendant_evolved_forms
    end
  end
end
```

#### Example Usage

```rb
oddish = Pokemon.find(1)
# => <Pokemon id: 1, name: "Oddish">

oddish.next_evolved_forms
# => [ <Pokemon id: 2, name: "Gloom"> ]

gloom = oddish.next_evolved_forms.first
# => <Pokemon id: 2, name: "Gloom">

gloom.next_evolved_forms
# => [ <Pokemon id: 3, name: "Vileplume">, <Pokemon id: 4, name: "Bellossom"> ]

vileplume = gloom.next_evolved_forms.first
# => <Pokemon id: 3, name: "Vileplume">

bellossom = gloom.next_evolved_forms.second
# => <Pokemon id: 4, name: "Bellossom">

# testing the nested methods:

oddish.ancestor_evolved_forms
=begin
{}
=end

oddish.descendant_evolved_forms
=begin
{
  <Pokemon id: 2, name: "Gloom"> => {
    <Pokemon id: 3, name: "Vileplume"> => {},
    <Pokemon id: 4, name: "Bellossom"> => {}
  }
}
=end


gloom.ancestor_evolved_forms
=begin
{
  <Pokemon id: 1, name: "Oddish"> => {}
}
=end

gloom.descendant_evolved_forms
=begin
{
  <Pokemon id: 3, name: "Vileplume"> => {},
  <Pokemon id: 4, name: "Bellossom"> => {}
}
=end


vileplume.ancestor_evolved_forms
=begin
{
  <Pokemon id: 2, name: "Gloom"> => {
    <Pokemon id: 1, name: "Oddish"> => {}
  }
}
=end

vileplume.descendant_evolved_forms
=begin
{}
=end


bellossom.ancestor_evolved_forms
=begin
{
  <Pokemon id: 2, name: "Gloom"> => {
    <Pokemon id: 1, name: "Oddish"> => {}
  }
}
=end

bellossom.descendant_evolved_forms
=begin
{}
=end
```

#### TODO:

add model validation to Pokemon to prevent "StackLevel Error" if somehow the "evolution" loops back to the start (which should never happen).

Comment: Thanks for this solution @Jay-Ar Polidario I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I`d say that You are on the right path but not quite there yet.
What could work for Your objective is a tree structure (a.k.a. hierarchy). So a pokemon would have many evolved forms and only one pre-evolved form to which it would belong (or the other way around). Based on just this one relationship the whole logic could work and You could access both all evolved forms and all pre-evolved forms for any single pokemon.

```
class Pokemon < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :pre_evolved_form, class_name: 'Pokemon', foreign_key: 'pre_evolved_form_id', optional: true
end
```

By implementing this Yourself, You would need to write helper methods to access both evolved forms (descendant objects) and pre-evolved forms (ascendant objects).
Though, I'd suggest for You to look into a gem called `ancestry` which should make things just a bit easier. Their readme seems well written so I`m not gonna try to explain it better then them.

Also look into hierarchical object structures.

Answer (score 0):

Always good to avoid reinventing wheels when you can.

You might find some benefit in the ancestry gem, which is used to organize models into a tree structure, which is what you are aiming for.

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry